# Exported JS Functions Require Imported?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a bit of JS for a group project and I had to write unit tests, so I modified all of my functions to be exported. That is, `function foo() {}` is now `export function foo() {}`.

I can import these functions and they work for my unit tests, but now they do nothing for the pages they were intended for, as if I have to import them in the same script before using them. Here is an example function that used to work but does not:

```
/*
Name: showLogin
Description: shows login box and hides sign up,
             exports for unit tests.
Parameters:
    showLogs - determines whether to print logs to console
*/
// 
export function showLogin( showLogs = false )
    {
        // check valid refs
        if ( checkRefs() )
        {
            // show login and hide signup
            login.classList.remove("hidden");
            signup.classList.add("hidden");

            // operation success
            return true;
        }

        // one or more refs are invalid
        return false;
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this. Thanks!

I tried modifying my JS functions to be exported so that I could test them but they no longer work on the pages they were intended for. They work fine where imported.

Comment: How do you mean "no longer work" - what is your expected result, and what is the current result? Can you show more about how you use the `showLogin` functions on the intended pages? It may not be the function is wrong, but how you config and use it that is wrong

Comment: The showLogin and showSignup functions basically hide and show two different `form` elements. They work when not exported but when I changed them to be exported (added the export keyword in front of the declaration) they do not work. I changed the call to them as `type="module"` instead of `script` which shows they work but for some reason now onClick does not recognize the function.

Comment: Where did you `import` and use them? I am not really well versed about this, but have you tried using `exports` and `require` syntax instead of `import` and `export`, if `import` and `export` is not working for you ?